# Как заполнить из массива сразу несколько столбцов в DataGridView через DataSource?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Пытаюсь заполнить сразу несколько столбцов строками в DataView через DataSource. Удалось заполнить только один - код ниже. Интересно, как работает DataSource в данном случае, почему просто не подсоединить массив двумерный, например.

```
string[] record = new string[] { "Б", "Б", "Б", "Б", "Б", "П", "П", "Б", "Б" };
dataGridView1.DataSource = record.Select(str => new { Name = str }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Удалось все-таки разобраться. Привожу ответ, может кому-то тоже пригодиться.

```
        string[][] array2 = new string[][]
            {
            new string[]{ "Col1row1", "Col2row1" },
            new string[]{ "Col1row2", "Col2row2" },
            new string[]{ "Col1row3", "Col2row3" }
            };
        var dd = from ar in array2
                 select new
                 {
                     Column1 = ar[0],
                     Column2 = ar[1],
                 };
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dd.ToList();
```